# how do i encode symbols in my html and php

Tags: php, html

Symbols such as: ♫

http://www.chatsmileysemoticons.com/music-symbol-twitter/

So that I can do something like:

```
    $tweet = '♫'.$tweet.$play_song_url;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writting your PHP source code in UTF-8, you can directly use that "special" character :

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$tweet = '♫' . ' Hello !';
echo $tweet;
```

Will get you the expected output -- I've just tried.

Note that your browser must, of course, display the page as UTF-8 -- this explain why I sent the correct header.

You can also use the HTML code of the character you want, and use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) to convert them to a single character :

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$tweet = html_entity_decode('&#9835;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . ' Hello !';
echo $tweet;
```

The problem being finding the right HTML-entity code ^^

Comment: What about URL encoding: `%E2%99%AB` I could not find a HTML entity for the note symbol and when I passed `&#9835; to twitter it did not decode it until after the posting of the tweet. However when I use the URL encoding it decodes it correctly... Although it show up as a box in the url...

Answer (score 4):

They're Unicode characters. Just make sure your HTML is UTF-8 and you can then use entities like:

```
&#8211;
```

For example: –

Comment: You can use a numeric character reference like this regardless of the page's charset. Using UTF-8 allows you to include `–` as a simple direct character instead of the escape.

Answer (score 3):

You can do one of two things:

1. Use HTML entities, these are the one you'll need: `&#9833; &#9834; &#9835; &#9836; &#9837; &#9838; &#9839;`
2. Encode your page as UTF8 and insert the symbols directly. You can do with with a meta tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score 0):

You can just echo out the html character entities, if supported. Something like

```
echo "You have my &hearts; so I'll give you a &diams;";
```

[Here is a good list of html character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).